# Composite function ...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the two functions:

$$f: x \in \mathbb{Z} \to 4 - x \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$g: y \in \mathbb{Z} \to |y| + 3 \in \mathbb{N}$$

The composite function is:

$$g \circ f: |4 - x| + 3$$

Please tell me if it's correct, thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Arthur If f is injective but g is not injective, that means that g o f is not injective? If f is surjective but g is not surjective, that means that g o f is not surjective?

Comment: @JonD I think it would be best if you post this as a different question, or search if this question is already answered in this site.

Comment: @idok I can't post questions anymore...

Answer (score 0):

> The *mapping* of the composite function $g \circ f$ is correct, but in order to fully specify the function it is crucial to also state *[domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function)* and *[codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain)* of the function.
>
> Using the notation above we can write
>   \begin{align*}
> g \circ f: x \in \mathbb{Z} \to |4 - x| + 3 \in \mathbb{N}
> \end{align*}

*Hint:* For instance in order to determine *surjectivity* of a function we also have to consider domain and codomain.